# Baking a Texture with Reflection coordinates

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

I am trying to bake a texture with Blender Internal on an object using Reflection Coordinates, I was using Normals Coordinates and a camera location to define the final result, but it doesn't work with Reflection Coordinates, the result is different than the camera view. Is there a way to achieve that with different settings?

[image]

Comment: Reflection depends on the view position.  Baking takes place from many points of view around the model.  It's unlikely you'll be able to get this to work.

Comment: @MarcClintDion If I use normal coordinates it bakes the texture exactly as the camera view, same for reflection coordinates but has a difference between the camera view and the bake, the difference is that in reflection coordinates not only the angle of the camera changes the bake but also the location. Since I posted the question there was improvement in the result in the latest versions of blender but still not as expected.